# Ojalgo: Defining whether a matrix is stable in Java

Tags: java, matrix, linear-algebra, ojalgo

I'm trying to solve M (NxN) linear systems (Ax = B, B = [b1,b2,...bM]) using Ojalgo. Thanks to **apete**'s counsel, I successfully managed to check if A (A, B are objects of type PrimitiveMatrix) is singular but it seems that sometimes it's also unstable..
It would be really useful for me to determine if this matrix is stable or not.

Any help would be most appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find the condition number of your matrix. I believe `getCondition()` gives you the condition number of a matrix. Bigger the number is less stable the matrices are.